# Auto Resize AG Grid columns on Zoom in & Zoom out?

Tags: javascript, events, bootstrap-4, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have two ag grid tables lined up side by side in a div. It functions properly on various screens and adjusts the column width automatically. The issue is that the function that is contained in the.js file does not activate when I zoom in and out of the screen; instead, I must reload the website to see the outcome. I have to reload the page each time I want the column width to automatically change to fit the width of the screen.

How can I avoid having to reload the page by running the function every time the screen changes?

[without Reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSQB1.png)

[With reload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNLBp.png)

html:

```
 <div  class="d-flex p-2 w-100">
                <div id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-alpine ag-theme-table1"></div>    
                <div id="myGrid2" class="ag-theme-alpine ag-theme-table2"></div>
  </div>
```

Js:

```
const columnDefs = [
    Objects here
];

// specify the data
const rowData = [
   Objects here
];

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    getRowStyle: (params) =>
        params.node.lastChild
            ? { backgroundColor: "white", "font-weight": "bold" }
            : null,
    onFirstDataRendered: onFirstDataRendered,
};

//function which is running on reload 

function onFirstDataRendered(params) {
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const gridDiv = document.querySelector("#myGrid");
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```